# Connecting Linux to Yaesu FT3D via bluetooth for audio into Direwolf?

Tags: linux, computer-control, direwolf

I'm looking to connect my Yaesu FT3D ham radio to a Linux laptop via bluetooth. I understand it only does audio over bluetooth, but for my use case that's acceptable.

My end goal is to run [Direwolf](https://packet-radio.net/direwolf) and do packet radio. I assume I'm limited to 1200bps since the FT3D doesn't expose the 9600 bps internal TNC it uses for APRS (when configured for 9600).

With no PTT control I'll be limited to either RX only, or using VOX.

So how do I do this? I assume there's a series of commands that will make it show up like a sound device on Linux?

Comment: This is really more a "how do I config BT on my desktop" than anything really to do with Ham Radio. [Here's a similar Q&A over on the Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205378/use-desktop-as-bluetooth-headset).

Comment: The series of commands: exactly what did you mean? Commands to or from the FT3D, or commands to the Linux OS?

Comment: Also, does the FT3D manual say anything about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @webmarc The migration was rejected on the target site. **I wouldn't object if it were reopened** here. Sure, it's [about Linux](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux), but it's also about amateur radio. Direwolf is for packet radio.
And many hams use Linux! :-)

Comment: Reopened by popular acclaim!

Comment: I expect this to be commands on Linux, so that it can act as the "headphones" and the "microphone" for the FT3D. I re-asked on unix.stackexchange framed as a Linux question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674067/how-do-i-connect-a-linux-machine-so-that-its-the-headphones-to-a-bluetooth-so

Comment: @MikeWaters the manual assumes I'll be connecting to a headset. If I can make Linux present as a headset, then the manual can guide me.

Comment: I just asked an [important question about this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674067/how-do-i-connect-a-linux-machine-so-that-its-the-headphones-to-a-bluetooth-so#comment1272622_674067) on unixSE.